# objective-c properties question

Tags: objective-c, properties

I'm new to objective-c and have been wondering what's the point of creating properties? I can just create a variable in the header? Why create a variable and a property with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an addition to what Joshua have said: properties are [KVC/KVO](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)-compatible while variables are not, whole Cocoa stands on **KVO**. You can bind a property and to property, you can add an observer, you can use valueForKey/valueForKeyPath and their 'set' brothers for free. If the value must be published (i.e. available for external classes) - make a property, you will get a lot of stuff for free. Just make sure you've set the proper memory management option (*assign*, *copy* or *retain*) and thread-safety modifier (*nonatomic*).

Comment: -1 Properties have nothing to do with KVC and KVO. KVC and KVO work fine without properties and do not even recognize them.

Answer (score 1):

Easier memory management (for some), better design (for all). Properties make your public interface to the class concrete, and it defines what is weakly and what is strongly referenced.